# Deleting a message from SQS after certain number of receives regardless of success/failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS queues in two places of my Spring boot application :

1. In one queue, I would like the messages to be routed to DLQ when maximum numbers of receives for a given message > = 3
2. For the second case, I don't like to configure a DLQ.

In (1) and (2), however, I would like to delete the message from DLQ and normal queue respectively after 3 times receives.

As of now, I cannot find any such configurations in SQS, that allows me to delete a message from the queue after a certain number of receives.

Maybe, I am missing something. Could anyone please help here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Why you just don't delete the msgs from the queue when you receive them?

Comment: @Marcin Actually I would like to receive the message 3 times before deleting them in case of any error.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no mechanism** for "automated" deletion of messages from SQS queue upon a given number of unsuccessful received, if you don't want to use DLQ.

Without DQL, SQS will keep messages in the queue till they **expire**. Thus, if you want to do what you wish, you have to create your **own solution** for that. You have to store number of times the message got  received, e.g., in DynamoDB, and then upon third receive, the consumer must explicitly delete the message from the queue.

Comment: I belive for DLQ also, the behaviour is the same. The message will stay there until it gets expired in case of failure.

Comment: @Joy Yes. You have to explicitly delete the message upon receiving it from DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore sqs message attributes. Once you received the message, delete it from the queue and send it back to the queue with an added message attribute stating how many times you have received the message.
Ref:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-java-send-message-with-attributes.html